# Screenshot определенной части экрана средствами html5

Tags: jquery, canvas, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.
Стоит такая задача:
Превратить содержимое div-блока в картинку и предложить пользователю скачать её.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width:200px;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://night-creature.com/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="downimg">
        <div>
            some text
        </div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">
        function downimg(){
            html2canvas($('#downimg'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

                    window.location.href = img;                     
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="downimg()" >SAVE</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Казалось бы, проблема решена. Но, изображение скачивается без расширения и даже без имени. Есть ли какой-либо способ, не привлекая серверные технологии, дать имя скриншоту?

Comment: [тыц](http://badassjs.com/post/12473322192/hack-of-the-day-rendering-html-to-a-canvas-element-via) ну а почему-бы не сделать ссылку с именем ? [canvas2blob](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

Comment: @eicto хм, действительно клёво! Сам искал, но не нашел, спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуте Inkognitoo, скажите пожалусто как реолизовали свой скрипт? Чтоб сахранялось с именем и расширением?

Comment: @Negash ответил на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download
в 5 версии добавлен волшебный атрибут, но я думаю не все браузеры его потянут

```
<a download="img.png" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="downimg()" >SAVE</a>
```

Comment: @ReinRaus Так же не получится заскринить некоторые данные сгенерированные на js, например графики, ну я во всяком случае на своей стадии развития не смог это победить

Comment: Сгенерированный WebGL тоже не получается заскринить.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, что без маленького серверного кода всё-таки не обойтись. C помощью javascript мы не можем изменить заголовок [Content-disposition](http://www.http11.ru/post.php?post=2), а это именно он задает поведение браузера - отобразить или сохранить. Всё-таки придется добавить десяток строк (вот [PHP-пример](http://www.kevinsookocheff.com/2011/07/27/saving-canvas-data-to-an-image-file-with-javascript-and-php/)), чтобы получить желаемое поведение.

Comment: Спасибо, всё это видел.

Answer (score 2):

Альтернатива есть - флешем сохранять. Сервер при этом не нужен.

- Исходники [GitHub: Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)
- Статья [Downloadify: Client-Side File Generation Using JavaScript and Flash](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify)

Comment: Нет, flash-технологии — persona non grata.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, у вас картинка генерится "на лету" и транслируется в `base64`. Соответственно вы получаете в `toDataURL()` не картинку, на всего лишь набор символов.

Comment: Благодарю, я знаю =)